in eleventy, how do I modify the response header, In the response header I want to add Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomain;

These is the response header I would want to put some HSTS/ Stric-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload, I already done using a way that I will add _header in the root folder but it doesn't work as expected same with using a middleware inside the eleventy.js and adding plugins also does not work either, Please help me with these.

11ty only generates static files. The serving and headers is up to your server, be it nginx or some third-party hosting. You can add custom headers with something like Cloudflare Pages, which is what I use.
